# PHP Customer Garbage Collcection

Tags: php, apache, garbage-collection

I have made a dummy session handler class while learning how sessions in php work.

I have the normal:

open, close, read, write, destroy and gc functions inside this class.

I have passed the class to a handler (when the class is created in has one parameter which is the db connection):

```
$handler = new Session($testdb);
session_set_save_handler(
  array($handler,'open'),
  array($handler,'close'),
  array($handler,'read'),
  array($handler,'write'),
  array($handler,'destroy'),
  array($handler,'gc')
);
session_start();
```

All of the functions inside this class have worked well - passing the data back and forth to the custom database as planned, accept the garbage collection. the gc function does not seem to want to play ball. When manually called it will work fine but php never seems to call it.

code block of the gc function:

```
  Public function gc($expire)
 { 
    $SessionInfo = new Delete($this->WebSite,array($expire),
    "DELETE FROM sessions
    WHERE DATE_ADD(LastAccessed, INTERVAL $expire SECOND) < NOW()
    ");
    echo '<H1>BIG LETTERS</H1>'; // HTML shout out if function is called //
    return true;
 }
```

I know there is a 1% chance on each session_start() that this is called but i have adjusted the % chance in my php.ini file so as to increase the chances to more 50% and tried several times to get this to actual be used. The fact that the function works fine when manually called and the fact that the other functions in the class work as they should ... leads me slighly stuck ... any ideas?

Comment: try to output this string into some log file and check values in it

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean instead of doing simple `echo` - write string to some file, like `fputs`

Comment: O I see - the function is working. I can manually see the echo if i use the function and i am checking the database at the same time. Nothing in the function can be wrong due to it working manually. I have double checked and its not due to having unexcpected number of paramaters or anything.

Comment: just try it and you will see that output is written into file, meaning - function works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

There were 2 problems:

1: In the function my query should have taken a "?" in the INTERVAL $expire SECOND line (so INTERVAL ? SECOND) ... I am still not sure HOW it was working at all when i spotted this. The class uses a PDO statement which should throw an error when a variable is inputted ... but yay thats another matter.

2: php.ini file was showing an incorrect probability chance for garbage collection ... likely down to previous editting on my part. (MAIN REASON)